# How can I let one struct contains another struct and a value produced by that struct in Rust?

Tags: rust

Actually the lexer's get_next_token will return a Token which has no relation to the lexer.
But the get_next_token method would borrow "mut self", so the compiler kept yelling "cannot return value referencing function parameter `lexer`".
How can I deal with it???????

```rust
  // in impl lexer
  fn get_next_token(&mut self) -> Token {
          let mut result = None;

          while self.current_char != None {
              match self.current_char {
                  // editing result
              }
          }

          if let Some(token) = result {
              token
          } else {
              Token::new(EOF, Nil)
          }
  }

struct Intepreter<'a> {
    lexer: Lexer<'a>,
    current_token: Token<'a>
}

impl<'a> Intepreter<'a> {
    fn new(mut lexer: Lexer<'a>) -> Intepreter {
        let current_token = lexer.get_next_token();
        Intepreter {
            lexer: lexer,
            current_token  // error!
        }
    }
}
```

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `lexer`
   --> src\main.rs:134:9
    |
133 |           let current_token = lexer.get_next_token();
    |                               ---------------------- `lexer` is borrowed here
134 | /         Intepreter {
135 | |             lexer: lexer,
136 | |             current_token
137 | |         }
    | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `lexer` because it is borrowed
   --> src\main.rs:135:20
    |
131 |   impl<'a> Intepreter<'a> {
    |        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
132 |       fn new(mut lexer: Lexer<'a>) -> Intepreter {
133 |           let current_token = lexer.get_next_token();
    |                               ---------------------- borrow of `lexer` occurs here
134 | /         Intepreter {
135 | |             lexer: lexer,
    | |                    ^^^^^ move out of `lexer` occurs here
136 | |             current_token
137 | |         }
    | |_________- returning this value requires that `lexer` is borrowed for `'a`
```

Comment: Could you please add the error the compiler gives you, as well as a minimalistic snippet of `get_next_token`, to understand what is the relationship between the lifetime of the returned token and the lexer?

Comment: We need more code than this to be sure, but it looks like since Token has a lifetime parameter it borrows something from Lexer, which seems to be what causes a problem.